# Delete button in MERN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

Why won't my delete button delete records? I'm using the mern stack. It looks like the state is not being set after console.log  code snippet 2. Code snippet 3 maps the data as if the record was never deleted. I understand that id is being pulled from the mongodb. Stack says this is mostly code so I'm adding more details to fill up space for no reason.

recordList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// This will require to npm install axios
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Record = (props) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{props.record.person_name}</td>
    <td>{props.record.person_position}</td>
    <td>{props.record.person_level}</td>
    <td>
      <Link to={"/edit/" + props.record._id}>Edit</Link> |
      <a
        href="/"
        onClick={() => {
          props.deleteRecord(props.record._id);
        }}
      >
        Delete
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
);

export default class RecordList extends Component {
  // This is the constructor that will store our data retrieved from the database
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deleteRecord = this.deleteRecord.bind(this);
    this.state = { records: [] };
  }


// This method will get the data from the database.
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://julio-mern-app.herokuapp.com/record/")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ records: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  // This method will delete a record based on the id
  deleteRecord(id) {
    axios
    .delete("https://julio-mern-app.herokuapp.com/" + id).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
    this.setState({
      record: this.state.records.filter((el) => el._id !== id),
    });
  }

  // This method will map out the users on the table
  recordList() {
    return this.state.records.map((currentrecord) => {
      return (
        <Record
          record={currentrecord}
          deleteRecord={() => this.deleteRecord}
          key={currentrecord._id}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  // This following section will display the table with the records of individuals.
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> JulioCorp Software </h2>
        <h3>Click 'Create Record' above to add your name if you are a...</h3>
        <h3>Amazing Individual!</h3>

        <h6>Make page wider if you do not see "Create Record" button. </h6>
        <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Amazing Quality</th>
              <th>Level</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.recordList()}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and record.js

```
const express = require("express");

// recordRoutes is an instance of the express router.
// We use it to define our routes.
// The router will be added as a middleware and will take control of requests starting with path /record.
const recordRoutes = express.Router();

//This will help us connect to the database
const dbo = require("../db/conn");

// This section will help you get a list of all the records.
recordRoutes.route("/record").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  db_connect
    .collection("individuals")
    .find({})
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(result);
    });
});

// This section will help you create a new record.
recordRoutes.route("/record/add").post(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  let myobj = {
    person_name: req.body.person_name,
    person_position: req.body.person_position,
    person_level: req.body.person_level,
  };
  db_connect.collection("individuals").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});

// This section will help you update a record by id.
recordRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  let myquery = { id: req.body.id };
  let newvalues = {
    $set: {
      person_name: req.body.person_name,
      person_position: req.body.person_position,
      person_level: req.body.person_level,
    },
  };
  db_connect
    .collection("individuals")
    .updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document updated");
    });
});

// This section will help you delete a record
//recordRoutes.delete("/:id") <----!!!!! add this and test!!!!!----
//recordRoutes.route("/:id").delete
recordRoutes.route("/:id").delete((req, res) => {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  let myquery = { id: req.body.id };
  db_connect
    .collection("individuals")
    .deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document deleted");
  });
});

module.exports = recordRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteRecord(id)
```

In this line, where are you getting the id from? and the issue could be in the link:
https://julio-mern-app.herokuapp.com/
here you have not provided the path of delete API

Answer (score -1):

Issue in your backend API code: The `DELETE` route in your backend API code is using `req.body.id` to get the ID for deletion, which is incorrect for a `DELETE` request. Instead, you should use `req.params.id` to extract the ID from the URL parameter.

Solution:
Update the line:

```js
let myquery = { id: req.body.id };
```

to:

```js
let myquery = { id: req.params.id };
```

This change ensures that the route correctly retrieves the ID from the URL parameter for deletion.